# Rails server runs, but rails console is throwing error "not checked out yet"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bundle

Rails server runs ok, but rails console won't start... What could be wrong?

```
user@user-pc:~/Sites/refcms_test$ bundle install
...#installing
Your bundle is complete!    
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.    

user@user-pc:~/Sites/refcms_test$ bundle exec thin start  
Using rack adapter    

-- DEPRECATION WARNING --    
The use of 'Refinery::Plugin#activity=' is deprecated and will be removed at version 3.1.    
Thin web server (v1.6.3 codename Protein Powder)    
Maximum connections set to 1024    
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

Server runs...but console not...

```
user@user-pc:~/Sites/refcms_test$ bundle install
...#installing
Your bundle is complete!    
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.    

user@user-pc:~/Sites/refcms_test$ rails console    
git://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-page-images.git (at master) is not yet checked out. Run `bundle install` first.
```

My versions Ruby & Rails:

```
user@user-pc:~/Sites/refcms_test$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-linux]
user@user-pc:~/Sites/refcms_test$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.6
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: have you recently updated to spring 1.3.x ?

Comment: Is this how you generated the app?  `rails new app_name -m http://refinerycms.com/t/edge`.

Comment: FrederickCheung - Gemfile.lock:    spring (1.3.1)
@AlokSwain - yes, it is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm facing the same problem today. And finally solved by upgrade `spring` from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:
    bundle install --deployment

Comment: SOLVED!! Thanks! Why? What is different?

Comment: This is not the best solution, it can bite you later. Better update to spring 1.3.2 and reverse previous changes with `bundle install --no-deployment`.

Comment: @zwippie could you explain why?

Comment: @alxndr That option is meant for deployment to a production server and should not be run on development (according to the [bundler manual](http://bundler.io/v1.8/bundle_install.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Stopping spring worked for me,

```
spring stop
```